# On-demand and seamless transcoding of individual HLS segments

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

## Background

I've been meaning to implement on-demand transcoding of certain video formats such as ".mkv", ".wmv", ".mov", etc. in order to serve them on a media management server using **ASP.NET Core 6.0**, **C#** and **ffmpeg**.

## My Approach

The approach I've decided to use is to serve a dynamically generated .m3u8 file which is simply generated using a segment duration of choice e.g. 10s and the known video duration. Here's how I've done it. Note that the resolution is currently not implemented and discarded:

```
public string GenerateVideoOnDemandPlaylist(double duration, int segment)
{
   double interval = (double)segment;
   var content = new StringBuilder();

   content.AppendLine("#EXTM3U");
   content.AppendLine("#EXT-X-VERSION:6");
   content.AppendLine(String.Format("#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:{0}", segment));
   content.AppendLine("#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0");
   content.AppendLine("#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD");
   content.AppendLine("#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS");

   for (double index = 0; (index * interval) < duration; index++)
   {
      content.AppendLine(String.Format("#EXTINF:{0:#.000000},", ((duration - (index * interval)) > interval) ? interval : ((duration - (index * interval)))));
      content.AppendLine(String.Format("{0:00000}.ts", index));
   }

   content.AppendLine("#EXT-X-ENDLIST");

   return content.ToString();
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("stream/{id}/{resolution}.m3u8")]
public IActionResult Stream(string id, string resolution)
{
   double duration = RetrieveVideoLengthInSeconds();
   return Content(GenerateVideoOnDemandPlaylist(duration, 10), "application/x-mpegURL", Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Here's an example of how the .m3u8 file looks like:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXTINF:10.000000,
00000.ts
#EXTINF:3.386667,
00001.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

So the player would ask for **00000.ts**, **00001.ts**, etc. and the next step is to have them generated on demand:

```
public byte[] GenerateVideoOnDemandSegment(int index, int duration, string path)
{
   int timeout = 30000;
   int totalWaitTime = 0;
   int waitInterval = 100;
   byte[] output = Array.Empty<byte>();
   string executable = "/opt/homebrew/bin/ffmpeg";
   DirectoryInfo temp = Directory.CreateDirectory(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName()));
   string format = System.IO.Path.Combine(temp.FullName, "output-%05d.ts");

   using (Process ffmpeg = new())
   {
      ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = executable;

      ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-ss {0} ", index * duration);
      ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments += String.Format("-y -t {0} ", duration);
      ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments += String.Format("-i \"{0}\" ", path);
      ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments += String.Format("-c:v libx264 -c:a aac ");
      ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments += String.Format("-segment_time {0} -reset_timestamps 1 -break_non_keyframes 1 -map 0 ", duration);
      ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments += String.Format("-initial_offset {0} ", index * duration);
      ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments += String.Format("-f segment -segment_format mpegts {0}", format);

      ffmpeg.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
      ffmpeg.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
      ffmpeg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
      ffmpeg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;

      ffmpeg.Start();

      do
      {
         Thread.Sleep(waitInterval);
         totalWaitTime += waitInterval;
      }
      while ((!ffmpeg.HasExited) && (totalWaitTime < timeout));

      if (ffmpeg.HasExited)
      {
         string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(temp.FullName, "output-00000.ts");

         if (!File.Exists(filename))
         {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Unable to find the generated segment: " + filename);
         }

         output = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
      }
      else
      {
         // It's been too long. Kill it!
         ffmpeg.Kill();
      }
   }

   // Remove the temporary directory and all its contents.
   temp.Delete(true);

   return output;
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("stream/{id}/{index}.ts")]
public IActionResult Segment(string id, int index)
{
   string path = RetrieveVideoPath(id);
   return File(GenerateVideoOnDemandSegment(index, 10, path), "application/x-mpegURL", true);
}
```

So as you can see, here's the command I use to generate each segment incrementing -ss and -initial_offset by 10 for each segment:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -y -t 10 -i "video.mov" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -segment_time 10 -reset_timestamps 1 -break_non_keyframes 1 -map 0 -initial_offset 0 -f segment -segment_format mpegts /var/folders/8h/3xdhhky96b5bk2w2br6bt8n00000gn/T/4ynrwu0q.z24/output-%05d.ts
```

## The Problem

Things work on a functional level, however the transition between segments is slightly glitchy and especially the audio has very short interruptions at each 10 second mark. How can I ensure the segments are seamless? What can I improve in this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the segment muxer, your input duration should be the sum total of the segments you need.

For segments 00002.ts to 00004.ts,

`ffmpeg -ss 20 -t 30 -copyts -i "video.mov" -map 0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f segment -segment_time 10 -reset_timestamps 0 -break_non_keyframes 1 -segment_format mpegts output-%05d.ts -y`

(you will run just one command for each contiguous set of output segments)

Comment: Thank you so much @Gyan, is it absolutely necessary to generate several consequent segments at once with this command? Or can I just generate one at a time? Also I can see you've used -copyts and I assume that replaces -initial_offset and is preferable right?

Comment: For video, to avoid small overlaps or frame drops, you *should* generate adjacent segments in the same command. For audio, to avoid glitches at segment boundaries, you **must** encode in one command. I suppose you could do the audio in one and video in multiple but then you would have to stitch while maintaining sync. That requires quite a bit of bookkeeping and logic.

Comment: Thank you @Gyan, I understand. Ah how I wish the segment muxer had the argument to just print out the segment timestamps/frames of each stream without actually encoding them. I suppose I'd have to resort to some caching anyway.

Comment: I'm actually very happy with this solution using ffmpeg 6.1 and individual segments. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

*Note:  I'd defer to @Gyan on this... he's the go-to FFmpeg person, but I wanted to give some practical notes and alternatives.*

I don't think you'll be able to seek into the source video and end up with accurate independent segment transcoding, in practice.  Especially if you're not in control of the files you're transcoding from, or when they're in a variety of formats.

Here are a couple on-demand transcoding methods I've used instead:

### Option A: Transcode only from the beginning, no seeking

This is a good option if your output will be reused for multiple clients.  Transcode once, cache the output, and you're good to go.  You can take care of multiple bitrates for ABR in the same FFmpeg process.

The downside of course is that if your client wants video further into the future, it's going to take some time for the transcoder to get to the segment the client wants.

### Option B: Seek the source, for the one client only

In this case, you seek into the source where the client wants and stream back the result, but *don't* assume any prior segments are going to line up.  Therefore, unless you have several clients making the exact same requests, there's little point to caching the output.

Also, if it's helpful, you don't need to use HLS for this.  Since you're streaming back to a single client and you know what bitrate you want, you can simply send the STDOUT from FFmpeg right to the client for playback.  No need to write out segments.

### Options A + B

Reality is, you'll probably need to use both of these methods.  If a request comes in for transcoding, you can start streaming from the requested point while enqueuing a background job to transcode the whole file.

Comment: Thanks @Brad! I think I'll take both your and Gyan's advice and implement a consecutive cached segmenting. However knowing perhaps too little about videos, I can't imagine why it would be impossible to use the same process as the segment muxer or hls muxer use to cut the streams to segments without transcoding anything just to compile a list of keyframes suitable for independently generating each segment on demand and storing that in the database.

Comment: @OmidAriyan Well, since you intend to transcode, you won't know where those keyframes are.  Also since you're doing HLS, you're going to want to introduce additional keyframes.  You also have the audio side, where if you're using AAC the frames may rely on other frames.  This is something the decoder sort of papers over when playback begins if data is missing, but that doesn't help you if you're intentionally creating segments separately.